# Way to turn variable into None if its original value is empty

Tags: string, robotframework

Is there a way to change a variable into None if it’s original value is empty?

I have tried following script

```
${searched_item}= Set Variable If ${searched_item} == “” None
```

I have also tried `${searched_item}= Set Variable If ${searched_item} == ${EMPTY} None`

For some reason this script changes every value into None even if they have some value such as “Rebecca”, “Apple”, or “tree”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a solution:

```
*** Variables ***
${test_variable}=    ${EMPTY}

*** Test Cases ***
Assign Value To Variable
      ${test_variable}=    Set Variable If    '${test_variable}'=='${EMPTY}'    ${None}    ${test_variable}
      Log To Console    ${test_variable}
```

I assume you mean `${None}` and not string "None", it's a bit unclear from your question.

Basically you forgot an "else" branch in `Set Variable If`, it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If). If you assume `${rc} == 0`, then it goes like this:

[image]

The red rectangle is where you have a missing value/variable.

There's an official documentation to read: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If

Comment: @New_to_coding: good. you can also mark my answer and a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there's some confusion about when to wrap variable in quotes in if statements in Robot Framework.

When using a keyword like `Run Keyword If` or `Set Variable If` the if statement is evaluated in Python, and any variables are substituted before it's evaluated. You need to take care when evaluating strings, by wrapping them in quotes.

Take for example:

```
${something}=   Set Variable   RobotRock
${new_val}=   Set Variable If   ${something} == ${EMPTY}   ${None}   ${something}
```

In the above if statement we are not enclosing either variable in quotes.

`${something} == ${EMPTY}` therefore equates to `RobotRock ==`  which isn't valid Python. You'd need to wrap it in single quotes in order for it to work since you're comparing strings.

```
${new_val}=   Set Variable If   '${something}' == '${EMPTY}'   ${None}   ${something}
```

Which now gives you: `'RobotRock' ==  ''` which IS valid python

Also, be careful if you try and compare something to ${None}. It's not a string, so you can't simple compare it in an if statement the way you might expect. You can find more information on None vs Empty and how to use them here: https://github.com/FormulatedAutomation/StupidRobotTricks/blob/main/empty-vs-none/tasks.robot#L45